# Auto-Type sudo password on CentOS 7.9

Tags: ssh, passwords, sudo

I have CentOS 7.9 and a SSH Config file which I use to SSH to the hosts in my network. I use a SSH keypair to SSH to the hosts and upon logging in, I run the sudo su command to become root. It then asks me for my password. Is there any way or any tool I can use so I don't have to type my admin password each time? Thank you in advance

Comment: login on remote machine directly as root (use ssh keys)

Comment: @RomeoNinov The company does not allow that. Everyone logs in as themselves with a SSH key, then sudo, I am trying to find a way (or a password manager tool) so it remembers my password and I don't have to type it every time I sudo